# laravel database where condition

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-4

Below is my laravel query to selct data...

```
$mydata = DB::table('History')
    ->where('Start','>=',$Start)
    ->andwhere('Start','<=',$End)
    ->select()->get();
```

Lets assume in database we have data from 3-10 (start).....user inputs

1)case 
    $start = 2;
    $end = 10;
2)case
    $start = 4;
    $end = 10;

using the query I am getting data between 3-10 for 1) case ...

In the first case,I dont want to display any data, in second case i want to display data between 4-10 only...condition should be something like

`start=data<=end` not `start<=data<=end`

i also tried ...

```
$mydata = DB::table('History')
    ->where('Start',$Start)
    ->andwhere('Start','<=',$End)
    ->select()->get();
```

but still not fixed any ways to fix this laravel?

Answer (score 1):

Your question has nothing to do with Laravel per se. In order to achieve your goal you have to probe your data in your query prior to filtering the resultset. Your query in plain SQL can look like this

```sql
SELECT h.*
FROM history h JOIN
(
  SELECT a.start, MIN(h.start) min_start, a.end, MAX(h.start) max_end
    FROM history h JOIN (SELECT 2 start, 10 end) a 
      ON h.start BETWEEN a.start AND a.end
) q
    ON h.start BETWEEN q.start AND q.end
   AND q.start >= q.min_start AND q.end <= q.max_end
```

This particular query will return an empty resultset.

If you change `(SELECT 2 start, 10 end) a` to `(SELECT 4 start, 10 end) a` you'll get

```
+-------+
| start |
+-------+
|     4 |
|     5 |
|     6 |
|     7 |
|     8 |
|     9 |
|    10 |
+-------+
```